# Mysql - Get the maximum value of each group for a given id, efficiently

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

We have a table where it records the scores of users at some games. What we want is to **show the max score of each user per game**. Note that may have been submitted 1000+ scores by each user, community is big(so users increase more and more) and there are a lot of games.
We already use this query found at a similar question here:

```
SELECT f1.userkey, f1.score, dateachieved, timeachieved, `MA_users`.username
FROM (
      (
        SELECT userkey, max( score ) AS score
        FROM `MA_scores`
        WHERE gameid = '$gameid'
        AND STATUS = 'approved'
        GROUP BY userkey
      ) AS f1
      JOIN (
        SELECT userkey, score, dateachieved AS dateachieved, timeachieved AS timeachieved
        FROM `MA_scores`
        WHERE gameid = '$gameid'
        AND STATUS = 'approved'
        GROUP BY score DESC , userkey
        ORDER BY `score` DESC
      ) AS T2 
      ON f1.userkey = T2.userkey
      AND f1.score = T2.score
)
JOIN `MA_users` ON f1.userkey = `MA_users`.userkey
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

The problem with the above is that it takes some time to complete, and as a result the site is not quickly accessible(delay for some seconds) (thus we've seen 50% cpu usage from mysql). 
We know this is the known greatest-n-per-group problem, and read some questions here, and some blog articles but they didnt seem to improve the speed of the query enough.

So the question is: Is there any even more efficient query to retrieve the desired results? Moreover, which indexes should be used with the query so to speed it up more? (in order to avoid Using filesort; Using temporary etc too)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of querying for it every time, what about having a so-called `Statistics` table where there are two columns: `userkey` and `max_score`. You could backfill this table easy enough; the trick will be keeping it up-to-date.

You could put a trigger on the `MA_scores` table for when a new row is inserted. The trigger would simply select MAX(score) from the table for that `userkey` and update the `Statistics` table.

I don't know how that fits in with your existing architecture or if it's even that great of an idea, but it would have blazing fast read times, and with proper indexes on the `MA_scores` table, could be quite fast overall.

Comment: thanks, i will mark it as accepted since noone else replied and as it is a clever answer :) and i think i could extend it more so to cache it, and delete the cache file when any new entry/update takes place in the Statistics table :)